# When asked if two graphs are the same, is the problem P, NP, NP-hard, NP-complete?

Tags: graph, computation-theory, np, np-complete, np-hard

I was given a question where two graphs are given and the questions asks if the two graphs are the same and whether the problem was a P, NP, NP-hard or NP-complete. By looking at the two graph, the graphs are not the same. However, I don't know what type of problem it is.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you have to define what you mean by "the same". There are several ways of defining equality, but the most likely one in this context is graph isomorphism, where two graphs are equal if there is an edge-preserving bijection between them.

Next, if the problem is just to decide if your two *given* graphs are the same or not (and this is how you stated it), the problem is trivially in O(1) (and therefore in P and NP).

If, however, the problem is to decide whether *any* two graphs are isomorphic, the problem is in NP. It is currently neither known whether it is in P nor whether it is NP-complete.